# iPhone 4 won't charge with wall charger after iOS 6 update

Tags: iphone, ios, charging

After updating to iOS 6.0 my iPhone will not charge on the wall charger.  My phone will charge in the car and on a stereo dock.  My wall charger still works and charges my iPod touch fine.  I have even tried my husband's wall charger and my phone still won't charge.  When I plug it in the wall charger just starts blinking and my phone starts alternating charge/off/charge/off.  I have restarted phone, held home and power key, even updated to the new iOS 6.01 and still nothing!  Help!

Comment: When you say the wall charger starts blinking, what kind of wall charger is it? It sounds like a third-party wall charger. What happens when you use the Apple-brand wall charger that came with your iPhone?

Answer (score -2):

Check the dock connector on the bottom for dust, and clean it out very carefully.

The wall charger uses a different pin for the faster charge rate (12V I think), USB only carries 5V of power, and has a dedicated pin on the dock connector for 5V charging.

Comment: The wall charger is still 5V, using the same (-) and (+) pins as regular USB. The only difference is that there is some resistor across the data line to tell the phone that it can use more current than a regular USB power source